# Accessing Multi-Level AJAX array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access data in a multi-level AJAX response sent by PHP (WP). I've read other q's on the topic that say I need to iterate through the result so I am trying this:

```
$j.each(result[0], function(key , value){ 
   // key, value
     $j.each(value, function(k , v){ 
        k,v
    })
})
```

...which gives me the below in console:

[image: array example]

I need to access just the values of each array so that they end up like this:

```
["2017-12-16", 128],
["2017-12-17", 105],
["2017-12-18", 76],
["2017-12-19", 107],
["2017-12-20", 93],
["2017-12-21", 46]
```

What I don't understand is after going down to a second `.each` why the result is the same as the first `.each` (both are same as image above). Could do with pointing in the right direction please. Many thanks.

*Update*
I made the result array I wanted into an object and accessed it as follows:

```
obj = result[0];
$j.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
   '["'+value[0]+'",', value[1]+'],'
})
```

...but this all became a moot point anyway as I was trying to add rows to a Google Chart and didn't need to iterate I just added the `obj` array and all was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this JSON result set into an array like this:

```
// Define results array
output=[];

// Iterate through objects in set, convert, and add to array
for (i in result[0]) output[i]=$.map(result[0][i], function(v, k){ return v; });
```

I do not have access to your original data set, of course, but I read what you posted to mean that the JSON lives in result[0]

Comment: Thanks sorak, I ended up using a different method but will try yours as well thanks.